# How would I turn a graphQL query into a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web-deployment, gatsby

In my gatsby project,specifically in `gatsby-config.js` I have a particular array of objects called `menuLinks`

```
siteMetadata: {
title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
description: `The official Flight Log and utility tool for the CF`,
author: `Tristan Rebello`,
menuLinks: [
  {
    name: "CF FLight Log",
    link: "/",
  },
  {
    name: "Crew Quarters",
    link: "/page-2",
  },
],
},
```

I am trying to implement my own navbar from scratch. Right now the navbar contains only two pages `CF Flight Log` and `Crew Quarters`. The graphQl query below pulls the `menuLinks` array which contains the information (name and link) for my pages.

```
/*links.js*/
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"

const {
  site: {
    siteMetadata: { menuLinks },
  },
} = useStaticQuery(
  graphql`
    query {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          menuLinks {
            link
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
)

export default menuLinks
```

Above, the menuLinks array contains the two link objects. I want to use menuLinks as an exportable object to be referenced in other components like so, on line 10:

```
/*index.js*/
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import menuLinks from "../components/links"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout title={menuLinks[0]} subpage=menuLinks[1]>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <h2>Welcome To The Official Flight Log of 3/1 </h2>
    <p>Here you can easily log your in-game flight hours</p>
    <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }}></div>
    <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

I get the following [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRjCl.png) however, when I run the app on localhost

Now the error says that my `links.js` file uses a hook called `useStaticQuery`. How would I convert that query which gets stored in `menuLinks` into a react component, *but* still be able to use it as an indexable array like so in `index.js` on line 10

Answer (score 2):

[useStaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/) is a custom React [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), and it's meant to be used in the definition of a function component. I.e: **You can't use a hook outside of a component definition**, and that is what the error is telling you.

The hook will load the data once per component mount, so if you want to avoid unnecessary hits to the API you can fetch that data in a parent component and pass it to the children:

```
const SomeComponent = _props => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(someQuery)

  return (
    <>
      <ComponentA data={data} />
      <ComponentB data={data} />
    </>
  )
}
```

This may or may not be a good solution, and is what we call "prop drilling" because you have to drill some value through arbitrary amounts of nested components.

A possible solution to the "prop drilling" problem could be to introduce global state of some sort. Using React [Contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) would be a good, light-weight approach.